# Search file for X and see if the file contains it or not - Python

Tags: python, file

I am making a simple battleship game with a computer for singleplayer mode. I don't want the bot to guess in the same place as it has already guessed. I have been trying to use .txt files as "logs" for old guesses, convert them to a list and then run through them with a "for" statement. The problem I am having is detecting when the entire file had NOT got the coordinates it has guessed. Is there a better way of doing this?

Here is the code WITHOUT detection for un-guessed guesses

```
import random
f = open("guesses.txt", "w")
guessing = True

while guessing == True:
    guess = random.sample(range(0, 4)2)
    f = open("guesses.txt", "r")
    f = f.readlines()
    for i in f:
        if guess == i:
            break
```

Thank-You so very much in advance
Files look like this:

```
[2, 3]
[3, 2]
[3, 0]
[1, 4]
[4, 3]
```

Comment: What does the format / value of an example guess or 'coordinates' look like?

Comment: It will be in a list format due to the generation Ex. [1, 0]

Comment: Ok, so a guess will be generated by the range function and be a list [0,1] for example and you want to store previous guesses in a list and not allow a user to select a previously guessed coordinate pair?

Comment: Yea, I have the full code on another computer but I left it at school :( (sorry) it can successfully record the guess but i can't for the life of me figure out how to search the ENTIRE list for matching cords before breaking out of the "guessing" loop.

Comment: Reread your post. So the coords are in a text file and you are reading them into a list then searching the list? If so, what is the format of the text file?

Comment: so it adds the randomly generated cord, then a new line, looks like this:
[1, 0]
[3, 4]
[2, 1]
EDIT: It is not adding the new lines

Comment: Do you need the brackets? Or do you want a list of lists?

Comment: It makes it easier for the hit detection but im sure i could work something out!

Comment: Alternatively, have you considered keeping a list of guesses in a variable instead of writing them to a files?

Comment: If Op stores them in a variable the program is dependent on past guesses being stored in memory.

Answer (score 1):

From what I’m getting, you could simply do something like this:

```py
with open("yourfile.txt", "r") as file:
    contents = file.read()
    if str(my_guess) in contents:
        print("The guess is not unique")
    else:
        print("The guess is unique")
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better way of doing this?

If I were writing a battleship game, I would either keep a list of guesses or a 2D array with guesses marked. I wouldn't bother with a file at all.

Files are intended for more permanent storage. For example, if you want to save a game and continue it later. They don't make sense for keeping track of the state of the game as you play it.